# Easy way to create an automatically generated grid of checkboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

A literal grid, of course; `Grid` isn't what I mean. Is there a preexisting control that would allow me to display a grid of checkboxes/toggleable things so that each row would correspond to an object, and each column would correspond to a property of the object? I'm looking for something more elegant/aesthetically appealling/fitting than just appropriating a `DataGrid` or `PropertyGrid` to display boolean "true" and "false" values. (Something like Dwarf Therapist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Checked Listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) in the Windows.Forms namespace, you might want to check a [WPF substitute](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21074/A-WPF-Problem-Solved-Two-Very-Different-Ways-Using%20%22WPF%20Checked%20Listbox).

Comment: Sorry, but I need to include multiple checkboxes for each field.